# Mysql - Woocommerce Cross Sell & Up Sell Single Product

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, woocommerce, product

I am trying to echo cross sell and upsell products in Single Product page. 
For Cross Sell I am getting MYSQL syntax Error

PHP: 7.0.21
MySQL:5.6.35

My Code

```
<?php
                    /* crossells */
            $crosssell_ids = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids' ); 

            $crosssell_ids=$crosssell_ids[0];

            ?>

    <?php

        $args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 8, 'post__in' => '$crosssell_ids', 'orderby' => 'rand' );
        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post(); ?>

                <li class="product">    

                    <a href="<?php echo get_permalink( $loop->post->ID ) ?>" title="<?php echo esc_attr($loop->post->post_title ? $loop->post->post_title : $loop->post->ID); ?>">

                        <?php woocommerce_show_product_sale_flash( $post, $product ); ?>

                        <?php if (has_post_thumbnail( $loop->post->ID )) echo get_the_post_thumbnail($loop->post->ID, 'shop_catalog'); else echo '<img src="'.woocommerce_placeholder_img_src().'" alt="Placeholder" width="300px" height="300px" />'; ?>

                        <h3><?php the_title(); ?></h3>

                        <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    

                    </a>

                    <?php woocommerce_template_loop_add_to_cart( $loop->post, $product ); ?>

                </li>

    <?php endwhile;  ?>
```

And frontend it shows

WordPress databasefout: `[You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp' at line 1]`

```
SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS wp_posts.ID FROM wp_posts WHERE 1=1 AND wp_posts.ID IN () AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-gplsquote-req' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'complete' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'paid' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'confirmed' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'unpaid' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'pending-confirmation' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'cancelled' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'wc-gplsquote-sent' OR wp_posts.post_status = 'private') ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 0, 8
```

Comment: the `IN` clause has no values to check: `IN ()`. That's where the error comes from. Did you write this SQL or is this generated by WordPress?

Comment: I just simply used above code and this generated by wordpress

Comment: Sounds like `$crosssell_ids` is empty or has no value, try `var_dump($crosssell_ids)` and confirm that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the problem is with the way you are getting the cross sell id's, I believe what you have is for an older version of WC, you can change your code as follows:

**Replace:**

```
$crosssell_ids = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_crosssell_ids' ); 
$crosssell_ids = $crosssell_ids[0];
```

**With:**

```
global $product;
$crosssell_ids = $product->get_cross_sell_ids();
```

---

**Update:**

You don't need quotes around `$crosssell_ids` in your `$args` array, try removing them:

```
'post__in' => '$crosssell_ids'
```

should be

```
'post__in' => $crosssell_ids
```

Comment: After replacing still : WordPress databasefout: [You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') AND wp_posts.post_type = 'product' AND (wp_posts.post_status = 'publish' OR wp' at line 1]

Comment: YES I add up sell and cross sell products in backend.

Comment: I did that but now it shows all the products in woocommerce instead of only cross sell products

Comment: <span class="price"><?php echo $product->get_price_html(); ?></span>                    
   

frontend:

<span class="price" style="display: flex"> </span>

If was echoing price when I was using product_cat instead of post__in now its not showing price. Any iDea ?

Comment: hmm.. is it a variable product(s)?

Comment: no I am using a plugin called appointment booking by bizz themes and below it I am showing cross and upsell products. Product data = Appointable product